# Is this green scale?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, citrus

I have a small orange tree, and for the last few days the leaves are getting sticky and some green bumps and small white dots appeared in the trunk and leaves.

From my google search it looks like scales, how can I solve this problem?

[image: Sticky leaves]
[image: White dots in the trunk]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing my best to view details of the white spots on the tree's trunk, it appears to me as thrips. There is a [close-up picture here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/insects/controlling-thrips.htm) for reference. Plus, this website offers some basic handling techniques. Removing infected leaves/branches and using pesticidal soap is the best immediate action, leaving more powerful pesticides when the first line of defense fails. The damage pattern on the leaves is also typical to such small insects.